# Have researched the RE module without finding a solution

Tags: python

Using python 2.7.5 and the following string. I am trying to sum  and  with the following code. Can someone steer me in the right direction? Thanks

```
<msg><src>CC128-v0.15</src><dsb>01068</dsb><time>09:19:01</time><tmprF>68.9</tmprF><sensor>0</sensor><id>00077</id><type>1</type><ch1><watts>00226</watts></ch1><ch2><watts>00189</watts></ch2></msg>

try:
    watts_ex = re.compile('<watts>([0-9]+)</watts>')
    temp_ex = re.compile('<tmprF>([\ ]?[0-9\.]+)</tmprF>') 
    time_ex = re.compile('<time>([0-9\.\:]+)</time>')

    watts = str(int(watts_ex.findall(data)[0]))
    temp = temp_ex.findall(data)[0].strip() 
    time = time_ex.findall(data)[0]
except:
    sys.stderr.write("Could not get details from device")
    sys.exit()

# Replace format string
format = format.replace("{{watts}}", watts)
format = format.replace("{{time}}", time)
format = format.replace("{{temp}}", temp)

print format

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

""" output is 09:19:01:, 226 watts, 68.9F (watts should = 415 watts """
```

Comment: Do you want to add the `<watts>` values together? Currently, you're just getting the first one.

Comment: yes, that is what I am trying to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an XML-like language, I'd strongly recommend using the XML libraries instead of regexes to parse it.

The problem in your code is this part:

```
watts = str(int(watts_ex.findall(data)[0]))
```

You're just using result `0` from the `findall()`, I think you want something like this:

```
watts = str(sum(int(w) for w in watts_ex.findall(data)))
```

Comment: Wolph, Your new line produced the following error: File "./current-cost3.py", line 96
    temp = temp_ex.findall(data)[0].strip() 
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Your answer worked after making some other changes in my code.